# Flutter I'm trying to add a tabbarview to my app, but nothing works, I want a tab to show cases from Brazil and another from the world

Tags: flutter

I tried to use NestedScrollView but was unsuccessful, I don't know where I can put the tabbarview how can I use tabbarview in this code

my app looks like this:
[image: my app looks like this]

```
  SliverToBoxAdapter _buildRegionTabBar() { //brasil e mundo
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
          height: 50.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white24,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          child: TabBar(
            indicator: BubbleTabIndicator(
              tabBarIndicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              indicatorHeight: 40.0,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            labelStyle: Styles.tabTextStyle,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab (text:'Brasil'),
              Tab (text:'Mundo'),
            ],
            onTap: (index) {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing TabBarView.

This is how it should be done. Modify this code to achieve your result:

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: 3,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      bottom: TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.flight)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
        ],
      ),
      title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.flight, size: 350),
        Icon(Icons.directions_transit, size: 350),
        Icon(Icons.directions_car, size: 350),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

For more info you can refer here : https://blog.logrocket.com/flutter-tabbar-a-complete-tutorial-with-examples/

Comment: doesn't work, I need to use the tabbarview inside the SliverToBoxAdapter and the tabs don't appear